# How to pass array of objects as a parameter to template

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates

I am trying to create a template that will accept a reference to a C-style array of objects as an argument:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
A(){}
};

template<int N, class A& obj> struct W {};

int main()
{
A b[5]; 
W<5,b> w; 
}
```

But when compile the code I get error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 -g try37.cpp
try37.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try37.cpp:14:5: error: the value of 'b' is not usable in a constant expression
 W<5,b> w;
     ^
try37.cpp:13:3: note: 'b' was not declared 'constexpr'
 A b[5];
   ^
try37.cpp:14:6: error: could not convert template argument 'b' to 'A&'
 W<5,b> w;
      ^
try37.cpp:14:9: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
 W<5,b> w;
         ^
```

I tried many ways but was unable to fix the compilation issue? How to resolve the same?

Comment: What about simply using `std::array` instead of raw arrays? Also note that template parameters refer to specify types, rather than objects.

Comment: I tried but it gives the same error. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: It does not resolves the compilation issue

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to achieve (this seems to me to be an XY Problem), I don't think you need that kind of template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : C style array is added to the answer.

if you trying to get struct W to have a container of objects you can use the vectors but. I'm still not sure why you want to do that.

```
struct W
{
    template<typename Type, typename A> //constructor with a vector
    W(std::vector<Type,A> & vec)
    {
       //...
    }

    template<typename Type>
    W(int arraySize, Type & obj) //constructor with an array
    {
       //...

    }
};

int main()
{
    const int ArraySize = 5;
    A b[ArraySize];
    std::vector<A> vec;

    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
        vec.push_back(b[i]);

    W w(vec); //calling struct W constructor that takes a vector.
    W w2(ArraySize,b); //calling struct W constructor that takes c style array
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My requirement is that I need to create the template with a specific number of instances of class A

Comment: im still not sure why you want the template. you already know what you want to pass to W. its a class A type. are you trying to  use Template to determine the size of the array you passing to the W? if so thats not the purpose of template arguments.

Comment: Class A is just used for an example - it can be just any other class

Comment: ah... i see that makes a huge difference

Comment: Actually it would be an interface and value passed will be an instance of object created from that interface

Comment: Can the constructor of W be changed to accept an array of instance of class A

Comment: Did you try to use `auto obj;`?

Comment: But still if I need to pass 5 instances if I declare as auto obj  any multiple instance can be provided?

Comment: @Programmer im not sure how to do it in arrays but i edited the answer for vectors. still though the vector that is passed down can only contain one type of object. so if you have class A class B etc. you cant store them in a  same vector and pass them over the struct W constructor

Comment: Thanks I think that would resolve the issue my side I can check the vector size - actually I am writing code for a module ensuring that a specific number of instances of an object needs to be passed.

Comment: @Programmer .. oh. glad it helped. when  i get the chance i'll look into passing C type arrays and edit my answer. Now i know why you wanted to pass the integer. that would have contained the size of the array I presume.

Comment: Yes - the size required will be calculated from another code algorithm

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code.

(1) if you want to pass a reference to an object as template parameter, you have to define it as `constexpr` and give it external <s>`static`</s> linkage (`static` is not necessary, correction from birdfreeyahoo (thanks!)), so

```
constexpr A b[5]; 

int main ()
 {
   W<5,b> w; 
 }
```

(2) if you want a (C-style array of) `constexpr` `A` object(s) initialized with default constructor, you have to make `contexpr` the constructor too.

So

```
public:
constexpr A(){}
```

(3) if you want that the second template parameter for `W` is a reference to a constant C-style array of `A`s, where the dimension is the first parameter, the syntax is

```
template <int N, A const (& obj)[N]>
struct W
 { };
```

So the full program become

```
class A
 {
   public:
      constexpr A ()
       { }
};

template <int N, A const (& obj)[N]>
struct W
 { };

constexpr A b[5]; 

int main ()
 {
   W<5, b> w; 
 }
```

Comment: The global variable doesn't need to be static, since that only determines the linkage type, the storage duration is static even without the keyword

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will only be able to pass 1 instance of A to the template.
Change it to `A[n] obj` 
Note: It will get converted to a pointer to A!

Second, the array you pass has to have static storage duration. So either make the array static or put it as global variable.

Comment: Thanks - but how can I make it to accept a non-global variable?

Comment: Make it static, but then it acts like a global variable which just can be accessed locally (but it stays the same each function call).

Comment: If you want to have a real local variable, you simply can't, because the pointer needs to be a constexpr, and this it can only be if the address is known at compile-time (so static storage duration). This is how templates work.

Answer (score 0):

```
template < typename TElement, std::size_t NElement>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_array( TElement const (&arr)[NElement] )
{
     (void)arr; // Unused, could have been anonymous
     return NElement;
}

template < typename TArray>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_array2( const TArray& arr )
{
     return ( sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] ) );
}
```

then in your code:

```
char arr[] = "abcdef;
sizeof_array(arr); // C-styled array
sizeof_array2(arr);
```